# Getting an "Exported queries are only executed for Page components." in Gatsby when trying to generate pages

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby, gatsby-plugin

This seems to be a relatively common problem. I am trying to generate blog post pages but am experiencing this error and the pages show a 404 on load. Which means that they are not being generated.

Here is my code for the `gatsby.node.js` file:

```
exports.createPages = async ({ graphql, useStaticQuery, actions: { createPage } }) => {
    const postQuery = graphql(`
      {
        gcms {
          posts(where: { stage: PUBLISHED }) {
              id
            slug
          }
        }
      }
    `);

    const {
        gcms: { posts },
      } = useStaticQuery(postQuery);
  
    posts.forEach(({ id, slug }) =>
      createPage({
        path: `/blog/${slug}`,
        component: require.resolve(`./src/templates/PostPage.js`),
        context: {
            id: id,
            slug: slug,
        },
      })
    );
  };
```

And my code for the blog post `PostPage.js` file:

```
/* eslint-disable react/prop-types */
import React from 'react';
import { graphql } from 'gatsby';
import Layout from "../components/layout";
//import galaxy from "../images/galaxy.jpg";
import SEO from "../components/seo";

export const postPageQuery = graphql`
  query PostPageQuery($id: ID!) {
    gcms {
      post(where: { id: $id }) {
        title
          slug
          excerpt
          postContentMarkdown
          tags
          author {
            name
            biography
          }
          seo {
            title
            description
            keywords
          }
      }
    }
  }
`;

const PostPage = ({data: {post}}) => {
    return (
        <Layout>
            <SEO
                keywords={[
                    `ui`,
                    `ux`,
                ]}
                title="Blog" />
            {post.slug}
        </Layout>
    );
};

export default PostPage;
```

Answer (score 2):

There are a few things that caught my attention and may fix your issue.

- The usage of [`useStaticQuery`](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/use-static-query/) in your `gatsby-node.js`. You don't need to fetch `postQuery` data with the static query hook since you are using the hook outside a component.
- The usage of `where` filter. According to [GraphQL documentation](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/graphql-reference/), the way to filter data is by using `filter` filter. In addition, when filtering the filtered criteria are strings, so must be quoted.
- When you pass a field via context API to your `PostPage`, you should avoid filter to all your `gcms` since your template has the information of that post, is not needed to redo the same previous query again (same than `gatsby-node.js`), it's not optimal. I will let it there since I don't know how is your data structured but should be refactored.

Applying it to your code should look like this.

`gatsby-node.js:`

```
exports.createPages = async ({ graphql, useStaticQuery, actions: { createPage } }) => {
    const postQuery = graphql(`
      {
        gcms {
          posts(filter: { stage: "PUBLISHED" }) {
              id
            slug
          }
        }
      }
    `);

    let {posts}= postQuery.gcms;
  
    posts.forEach(({ id, slug }) =>
      createPage({
        path: `/blog/${slug}`,
        component: require.resolve(`./src/templates/PostPage.js`),
        context: {
            id: id,
            slug: slug,
        },
      })
    );
  };
```

`PostPage.js:`

```
/* eslint-disable react/prop-types */
import React from 'react';
import { graphql } from 'gatsby';
import Layout from "../components/layout";
//import galaxy from "../images/galaxy.jpg";
import SEO from "../components/seo";

export const postPageQuery = graphql`
  query PostPageQuery($id: ID!) {
    gcms {
      post(filter: { id: $id }) {
        title
          slug
          excerpt
          postContentMarkdown
          tags
          author {
            name
            biography
          }
          seo {
            title
            description
            keywords
          }
      }
    }
  }
`;

const PostPage = ({data: {post}}) => {
    return (
        <Layout>
            <SEO
                keywords={[
                    `ui`,
                    `ux`,
                ]}
                title="Blog" />
            {post.slug}
        </Layout>
    );
};

export default PostPage;
```

Answer (score 2):

I ended up fixing this by doing a complete recomposition of my project, with an update to the latest version of Gatsby, this with a bare bones gatsby starter, plugin by plugin. It ended up being plugin conflict issue. I'm not sure which plugin exactly it was, but most likely it was one of these:

`gatsby-plugin-eslint`,  `gatsby-plugin-offline`, `gatsby-plugin-root-import` or possibly the `prop-types` NPM package.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced this same issue after upgrading to the latest version of Gatsby.

Similarly to Tapha's answer, it was a plugin conflict for me. I had yet to upgrade the `gatsby-source-strapi` plugin. Upgrading that package to its latest available version solved the issue. Whatever your data source happens to be, I would check that it's still playing nice with Gatsby.

So, **this warning/error message is very misleading**, *you can* still use an exported query from templates, as detailed in the Gatsby documentation [here](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/programmatically-create-pages-from-data/).